Severely underperforming during my internship. How do I tell my PI that I want to do more to get a first authored poster at least? Or, am I unfit?
I'm a soon to be a 4.5 year Ph.D candidate (ABD) in Experimental Psychology. A few weeks ago, I started an internship at a nationally recognized hospital in central Ohio (for the summer) that took 9/90 folks. I strongly considered quitting at first due to the culture shock at transitioning to office life, but I've been repeatedly told the importance of seeing my commitments all the way through. So, here I am now trying to survive this internship.
My PI (aka my boss) is also nationally recognized and has had an h-index of 90 within the past few years alone in Clinical Psychology. He formatted the internship similar to an advanced undergraduate class he taught where he was previously a full tenured professor. His expectation by the end of this internship is that we have at least one first authored poster by the end of it. He's extremely confident because his last class not only pulled that off, but this internship is literally research for 40 hours a week. My application in particular was considered the "dark horse" because my hometown is near the hospital. I was taken because I got a visiting full time instructor position at a SLAC this past academic year (those who've followed me know I bombed this horribly) and I mentioned I've taught statistics concepts in past Research Methods classes I've taught.
So far, I've spent half of every workday only meeting expectations and not going above and beyond that. I'm also working on upwards of three projects at a time, which is coordination I've never ever done before at all because I've worked on one project at a time all throughout graduate school up until this point. I'm also a bit afraid of the upcoming poster presentation as well as speaking in person given the universally negative course evaluations I received last time (I even rejected an offer for a full time lecturer position I recently got partially for that reason. However, the bigger reason is staying with my parents so I have a support system to recover from my major health issues, including my most recent diagnosis of moderate sleep apnea).
Fast forward to now and my boss has a points system to determine authorship for potential publications and manuscripts that he said he'll flesh out sometime this coming week. The problem right now is that I've been on 3 projects where I don't do much of anything unless duties have been delegated to me. What makes things worse is that everyone in this internship already had transferable skills to the position other than me. For example, I'm on the Data Science team and one of the students has extensive experience in R. Anything he accomplishes, he credits as a team accomplishment. The Clinical Psychology students are also working on other projects and are close to, if not already, lined up to be second authors at the very least. It's been three full weeks out 14 and folks are already doing circles like this.
What can I do at this point to try and remedy the situation? Or, is this potentially something where I may not be a fit and express concern to my PI/boss?

You don’t know if there is a situation to remedy yet.

What you say sounds more like culture shock (as you note) and a learning curve than it does like incompetence. You can't expect to master a new environment in a few weeks.
You could have a talk with the boss to get his opinion and pointers about what to do to succeed.
But, again, a few weeks is too soon to give up. Keep pushing.
